# Error con fetch api

Tags: javascript, nodejs, fetch

Tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy tratando de consultar una api con fetch, pero no se porque me da error, ya probé realizar la consulta en insomnia y funciona bien la petición.
Parece ser un problema de política con cors pero como recien estoy aprendiendo a usar fetch asi que no se muy bien como funciona.

```
const url_reservas = `https://api.estadisticasbcra.com/reservas`;

const obtenerReservas = async() => {
    try {
        
        const datos = await fetch(url_reservas, {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {               
                'Authorization' : 'lo borro por las dudas'
            }
        }); 

        return await datos.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const datos = obtenerReservas();
console.log(datos);

let fechas = [];
let valores = [];

for(let x in datos) {
    fechas.push(datos[x].d);
    valores.push(datos[x].v);
}

console.log(fechas);
```

Y me tira este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probaste añadir ``mode: 'no-cors'`` en el objeto de opciones que pasas como segundo parametro del fetch?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, si ya probe, el error se va pero no me tira los datos, tira error 403 (forbidden)

Comment: claro, a la api del banco no le debe gustar el localhost en la url que consulta los datos. Esto por ahi es mucho laburo pero tal vez te ayuder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: Luego tira Unexpected end of input en la linea 17:  return await datos.json();

Comment: Por seguridad, el navegador no te va a permitir hacer peticiones externas desde una página donde no tienes un certificado de seguridad o desde protocolo no seguro `http://`. Intenta instalar un certificado de seguridad en tu equipo, tal vez [esta guía](https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/como-generar-certificados-https-para-desarrollo-local-que-no-produzcan-errores) te pueda servir.

Comment: Probé a realizar la consulta desde un dominio con https desde netlify y me sigue tirando el mismo error.